# undefined index by selecting data from two tables with a common column

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables - `home` and `posts`;
`home.artid` is equal to `posts.id`.

Want select `id, artid, inde` from `home` PLUS `title` from `posts`
where `home.pos` is `slider`:

```
$items = "";
$st = $db->query("select home.id, home.artid, home.inde 
                    from home 
                        join posts on home.artid = posts.id 
                    where home.pos = 'slider' 
                    order by home.inde asc");
while ($row = $st->fetch()){
    $items .= "<div class='slidertitle'>" . $row['posts.title'] . "</div>\n";
}
echo $items;
```

Error:
Undefined index `posts.title...`

Any help?

Comment: You haven't selected that column.

Comment: (apart from not selecting) wouldn't it just be `title`?

Comment: @Xorifelse sure would

Comment: There are a bunch of typo's going on here: `ems .= "div ` ~> `ems .= "<div ` .. `home.inde ` ~> `home.index`

Comment: @Xorifelse `div` corrected, `inde` is ok, that's name of column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select `posts.title` then select it

```
$st = $db->query("select home.id, home.artid, home.inde, 
                        posts.title
                from home 
                    join posts on home.artid = posts.id 
                where home.pos = 'slider' 
                order by home.inde asc");

// and it would be called just `title` 

while ($row = $st->fetch()){
    $items .= "<div class='slidertitle'>" . $row['title'] . "</div>\n";
}
echo $items;
```

Comment: @puerto Then upvote & mark it when you can, says thank you enough.